# When serving my angular application memory usage goes to 100% and application doesn't load

Tags: angular, typescript

When attempting to serve my angular application the app seems unresponsive, I then noticed that no matter what my memory usage would go through the roof and at times my browser would give me an error regarding running out of memory, I have tried clearing the cache, re creating the application, removing all the npm modules and re installing them, I was just wondering what to look for as I have not written alot of the code in this project.

Comment: Could you please check whether there is any infinity loop working in background?

Comment: If it's an actual angular project, you can start by looking at the bootstrapped component (usually `app.component.ts`) and comment out code until the application stops using so much memory.

Comment: Wow, you were in a sense both right, there was a set user function being called which seemed to be doing it indefinitely, commenting this out under the ngOnInit in app.component.ts seemed to have stopped the memory issue, thank you!